# Reading a number range

Tags: readings, numbers

I have a bottle of 洗顔料(facial soap), and the instructions are:

> ご使用量の目安　ポンプ`１～２`回 (use about 1 to 2 pumps)

If I were to read `1~2` aloud, how would I do it?

Comment: for `１〜２`, I'd be tempted to read it like `１、２`... but no idea for a bigger range. Interesting question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the numbers are consecutive, you would just count and adjust the last number accordingly.  In this case, `いち、にかい`.  If it were, say, 5-6 times, `ご、ろっかい`.

If it's an actual range, I think you'd just throw から in the middle.  1-5 = `いちからご`.

Answer (score 7):

I think the most standard is `1から2`. You can also read it as `1乃至2`.