# How to read: the "~" (tilde) in "3~4 行"

Tags: readings, numbers, symbols

How should I read the "~" mark that stands for range, as described in the title?

I saw this in the following sentence:

> 3~4行ごとに1行あけると読みやすい。

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a number range](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2910/reading-a-number-range)

Comment: @istrasci Yes, but the answer here is much better.

Comment: We can potentially close the *other* question as a duplicate of this one, even though this is newer.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is no strict rule about this. It's best not to use this "～" symbol denoting a range, when it's meant to be read out loud by someone.

But if you really have to, you can read the "～" symbol as "から" in many cases.

> - 3～4行ごと　さんからよんぎょうごと
> - 2月3～5日　にがつみっかからいつか
> - 15～17階　じゅうごかいからじゅうななかい or じゅうごからじゅうななかい
> - 500～600円　ごひゃくえんからろっぴゃくえん or ごひゃくからろっぴゃくえん

Note that this sounds like you strictly specify the range of numbers. If you say like this, it means "three or four lines; not five nor two".

Alternatively, in this case, you can use the common idiom "さんよん", which more vaguely refers to the range *around* it.

> - 3～4行ごと　さんよんぎょうごと
> - 2～3日間　にさんにちかん
> - 4～5回　しごかい
> - 500～600円　ごろっぴゃくえん

These are closer to English "a few", "several", "a couple of", etc.

Comment: Nice! Very clear.