# How to pronounce １２歳〜１４歳

Tags: pronunciation, abbreviations

Could someone please explain how the Japanese would read the 〜 if they came across a range expressed like this:

> [１２歳]{じゅうにさい}〜[１４歳]｛じゅうよんさい｝

Comment: related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21679/how-to-read-the-tilde-in-34-%E8%A1%8C/21681#21681

Comment: Is this question related, or is it a duplicate?

Comment: It is a duplicate. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: じゅうにさい　から　じゅうよんさい　（まで）