# How to pronounce 5,60年?

Tags: pronunciation, numbers

I came across this sentence:

> 5,60年後の人々の生活がどう変わっているかとても想像できません。
>
> I cannot imagine how the lifestyles of people will change after fifty, sixty years.

I am wondering how to pronounce the 5,60年 part. Is it ごじゅうろくじゅうねん or ごろくじゅうねん? Or does both work?

Comment: Related: [How to read the "~"](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21679/15816) has similar answer for the pronunciation, only the difference is use of tilde instead of comma.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read: the "~" (tilde) in "3~4 行"](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21679/how-to-read-the-tilde-in-34-%e8%a1%8c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ごろくじゅうねん.

2,30年 is にさんじゅうねん.

Comment: When searched in reverse, found this relevant text: [「にさんじゅうねん」と書くときの正しい表記を教えて](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10117237210).

Comment: usually they use 漢字 with 読点 therefore it's 二、三十年.