# How is 件 pronounced as a counter?

Tags: pronunciation

In my bank statement there  is the following line above transactions.

1-6件を表示(全6件中)

How is the above pronounced?

What is the meaning of 中 in 件中?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> いち[から](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21679/5010)ろっ**けん**をひょうじ　ぜん ろっ**けん**ちゅう
>   Showing 1–6 of (a total of) 6 items

件 is a counter for issues, transactions, topics, database records, search results, etc. 件 is always unvoiced けん whatever number comes before it. Unlike 件, [軒](http://www.punipunijapan.com/japanese-counter-ken/) is sometimes voiced.

In this context 全【ぜん】 is "a total of", 中【ちゅう】 is "among" or "of".

Comment: As a side question: The dash is pronounced から, with no corresponding まで or anything like that? So essentially “Showing items from one six”? **Edit:** Oh, or maybe more like “Showing six items [starting] from 1”. That makes more sense.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Please visit the link at から.

Comment: Ah, sorry—missed the link completely. What an odd usage.